# Android: finding a directory

Tags: android, search, directory

Is there any way to find / search for a particular directory in Android? Like a user has made a directory with the name of MyHolidayVideos at any location. I want my application to find out where that folder is. Is there any way to search directories and find the location of the folder (MyHolidayVideos etc).. 
I shall be thankful if someone can help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The [Data Storage Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) has the information you need to get started. Specifically [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and [Using the External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) sections and the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) API.

Comment: Can you please elaborate here Sir. How can I search a specific directory in Android?

Comment: Sir, I shall be really thankful to you if you elaborate a little more on it.. I am also searching for a solution..

Comment: Thankyou Sir, I sorted it out myself but thanks for your help.. The document also helped me.